# Search a keyword from an array in an input string and Print them

Tags: java, regex, string, search, string-search

I have been doing this since almost past few days but still unable to get a required output.
Well I have an array say
 `wordlist[]={"One","Two","Three","Four","Five"};`
and then i take input from the user.

```
String input="I have three no, four strings";
```

Now what i want to do is perform a search operation on the string to check for the words available in the array wordlist[];
Like in the above example input string contains the words three and four that are present in the array.
so it should be able to print those words from array available in the string, and if no words from the wordlist[] are available then it should print "No Match Found".

Here's My code i'm struck with this.
Please

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;
class StringSearch{
    public static void main(String ...v)throws IOException{
        BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String wordlist[]={"one","two","three","four","five"};
        String input=cin.readLine();
        int i,j;
        boolean found;
        Pattern pat;
        Matcher mat;
        Pattern spliter=Pattern.compile("[ ,.!]");
        String ip[]=spliter.split(input);
        System.out.println(ip[2]);
        for(i=0; i<wordlist.length;i++){
            for(j=0;j<ip.length;j++){
                pat=Pattern.compile("\b"+ip[j]+"\b");
                mat=pat.matcher(wordlist[i]);
                if(){
                        // No Idea What to write here
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: in the if condition put `mat.matches()`. In the if body increment a counting integer and use it outside the for loops to print "no match found" in case of zero matches. Also check that `"\b"+ip[j]+"\b"` regex, it doesn't work to me

Comment: @Oneiros `matches` add `^` and `$` so it should be the complete match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `matches` with condition `input.matches(".*\\b"+wordlist[i]+"\\b.*")`

`.*` : match anything

`\\b`: word boundary to avoid matching `four` with `fourteen`

and `wordlist[i]` is your word

1.) Traverse your array using loop

2.) Pick words from array and use `matches` with given regex to avoid matching `four` with `fourteen`

```
    String wordlist[]={"one","two","three","four","five"};
    String input="I have three no, fourteen strings";
    int i;
    boolean found=false;
    // Traverse your array
    for(i=0; i<wordlist.length;i++){
           // match your regex containing words from array against input
            if(input.matches(".*\\b"+wordlist[i]+"\\b.*")){
                // set found = true
                found=true;
                // display found matches
                System.out.println(wordlist[i]);
            }
        }
    // if found is false here then mean there was no match
    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("No Match Found");
    }
```

Output :

```
three
```

Comment: @IVANPAUL i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Using Java8 Streams you can do:

```
 ...
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.stream.Collectors;
 ...

 String wordlist[]={"one","two","three","four","five"};
 String input=cin.readLine();
 String foundStrings = 
       Arrays.stream(wordlist)
       .filter(s->input.matches(".*\\b"+s+"\\b.*"))
       .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

 System.out.print(foundStrings.isEmpty() ? "No Match Found\n": foundStrings);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this, it is showing various errors when i tried compilling your code. Which update of java 8 do i need to use to make the code error free I am currently using update 77. showing cannot find symbol errors on **Collectors** and **Arrarys**.

Comment: You have to import `import java.util.stream.Collectors;` and 
`import java.util.Arrays;` I'll change the code to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks fella.  I'm completely new to streams.  Thanks a lot

Comment: Remember to accept an answer. I think that of Pavneet Singh would make more sense because it is better explaining the regex, I wrote mine just to show a more compact way to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here preparing a regex : \\b(one|two|three|four|five)\\b and checking the count of matcher.

```
String wordlist[]={"one","two","three","four","five"};
String input="I have three no, fourteen strings";

StringBuilder regexBuilder = new StringBuilder("\\b").append("(").append(String.join("|", wordlist)).append(")").append("\\b");
String regexExp = regexBuilder.toString();
regexBuilder.setLength(0);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexExp);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);

int count = 0;
while (matcher.find())
{
      System.out.println(matcher.group());
      count++;
}

if( count == 0){
    System.out.println("No Match Found");
}
```